# Two Windows Boot Manager entries in BIOS boot section

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi, bcd

I have in dual boot Arch Linux and Windows 11.

In my BIOS or when, at boot, I press key for boot selection, I have two Windows Boot Manager despite I have only one Windows installation.

If I run in Windows CMD the command `bcdedit /enum firmware`, I get:

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {ddb06b1f-6133-11ee-a5c3-806e6f6e6963}
                        {bootmgr}
                        {db70feaf-6179-11ee-a5c8-806e6f6e6963}
timeout                 1

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {3d596ea5-6131-11ee-a5c2-806e6f6e6963}
displayorder            {current}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {db70feaf-6179-11ee-a5c8-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {ddb06b1f-6133-11ee-a5c3-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
path                    \EFI\GRUB\GRUBX64.EFI
description             GRUB
```

and, on System Configuration of Windows, under **Boot** tab, I have only one entry:
[image: screen]

When I run `efibootmgr` on Linux, I get:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,71e827d6-2276-46f2-816b-881e51c53d30,0x800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d0000000c000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001* GRUB  HD(1,GPT,71e827d6-2276-46f2-816b-881e51c53d30,0x800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,4ae5c801-ebf3-be4c-a9b3-cab7a69f40a8,0xd6800,0x1da5a7f9)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)0000424f
```

The bad one is **Boot0002** (that is not working when boot to it). If I remove it by `sudo efibootmgr -b 2 --delete-bootnum`, and I re-run `efibootmgr`, it actually disappears, but when I reboot, it appears again, and indeed that entry is still in BIOS. It is like it is generated at reboot when I delete it.

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an EFI entry only hides it, which explains why it
"comes back".

Note that the two Windows entries are not on the same disk : One is
on HD1 and the other is on HD2. I suspect that the Windows installation
changed disks in your setup, which is why there are two
non-duplicate entries.

[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)
should be able to remove the non-working Windows entry.
Just be careful when doing that.

Comment: Grub Customizer shows only entries in GRUB and there, I don't have the two Windows entries. The two Windows Boot Manager entries are only on BIOS boot section. But you're right, I found boot files inside the second disk in the wrong partition. I deleted them and now the bad Windows Boot Manager entry has been deleted.

Comment: After this deletion, I deleted that wrong entry by `sudo efibootmgr -b 2 --delete-bootnum` where `2` was related to `Boot0002` of my output above. This command effectively deletes the bad boot entry after the deletion of the related `EFI` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Good this was solved. With DiskGenius we can list all Boot Manager entries that bcdedit can't show. We can rename, edit, delete, hide, add entries, edit paths, show full details of entries and it's friendly. Go to Tools > UEFI BIOS boot entries.
[image]